# Get euler rotation from Quaternion?

Tags: three.js

I'm using FlyControls for moving and rotation my plane (I'm doing a flight sim), and it works pretty well. However now I have ran into a problem where one possible solution would be to know the euler angles of my plane.
Unfortunately FlyControls is using Quaternion. Is there a possible way to get the angles somehow? Of course, I could rewrite the FlyControls module to use euler angles. But I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var rotation = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion( quaternion, eulerOrder );
```

three.js r.69